# Detecting auto-translation event in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, google-tag-manager

I'm currently expanding the type of data my nonprofit collects via Google Analytics/Tag Manager relating to website visitors accessing automatically translated versions of our website. I have a  some javascript that detects when people using Google Chrome have our website auto-translated (there's a class and "lang" attribute added to the  element in the DOM).

```
<html lang="en" class="translated-ltr">
```

I am trying to do something similar for Edge because I know that it has a similar auto-translation extension called Translator. Does anyone know if Edge's auto-translation causes any mutations or changes to the DOM when it translates a webpage?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I checked some websites in Edge Chromium and I found that after translation these attributes: `_msthash="149916" _msttexthash="64220390" _msthidden="1"` will be added in `<title>` element. The values of `_msttexthash` are different, the others are the same in different browsers.

So I think you can check `_msthash="149916"` or `_msthidden="1"` in `<title>` element to detect if people are using translator in Microsoft Edge Chromium.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. The one thing missing, which would be of equal importance to our analytics is what the new language is that Edge is translating the page to. Sadly, those attributes on `<title>` don't include a language code or anything similar.

Comment: Yes. It seems that there's no regularity of the attributes' values in `<title>`. So I think we can't tell what the new language is that Edge is translating the page to.

Comment: Seems like a feature request for Edge might be the only way to get that kind of information unless you have other thoughts/ideas.

Comment: There's no other ways than send a feature request. You could use the Feedback Hub (Alt+Shift+I) in Edge Chromium to send your feedback.